# How to change incorrect Wi-Fi password?

Tags: wifi, password, settings

I went to a coffee shop that had Wi-Fi this morning and they gave me the network name and password. In the top-right corner of my desktop there is the Wi-Fi menu, and I selected it to "Turn Wi-Fi On" It searched for a few seconds and correctly found their network.

I then tried to connect to it, but botched/fat-fingered the password and pressed <kbd>Enter ⏎</kbd> by mistake. I then wasted about 20 mins trying to find a way to change the (bad) password that my Mac was using to authenticate with. I gave up and came home.

So I ask: **How do you change the password for a Wi-Fi network?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways to do this...

#### Modify the Password in Keychain

You can do this under *Keychain Access*.  You will find all your saved Wi-Fi networks under the "System" keychain in the "Passwords" category.

Double clicking on the SSID (mine are redacted for security) will bring up a dialog box with the details for that particular Wi-Fi network.  From here, you can enter in a new password.

[image]

#### Delete the Network & Rejoin

You can also solve the issue by deleteing the network and rejoining it.  Simply go into your System Preferences > Network and select your Wi-Fi Adapter.  Click on the Advanced... button and you will be able to delete your Wi-Fi Network.  Just rejoin and enter in the good password.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to **Apply** the change on the main Network window, after **OK**ing out of the Wi-Fi window. That might be the reason it's failing.